# Write partial changes back to XML?

Tags: java, xml, dom, synchronization

I have my application data stored in XML file. This file is readed when app starts and writed back when it stops.

Are there any means in DOM or other libraries to keep data in sync with my objects? I.e. I wish to write back only what was changed?

Comment: In my opinion that seems rather difficult. You will have to write the entire XML file even if you change only a small part of the XML document. In computing, we can only write a file from top to bottom. Its difficult to detect a point 'somewhere in the middle' to overwrite, unless you are using a random access file structure in your XML files, which is needlessly complicated.